# UIView wont fit whole screen white bar shown at top of screen

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a `UIView` which is a subview of a `UIScrollView` and I want the `UIView` to cover the whole screen at the top of the `UIScrollView`, However when I load the app there is a white bar at the top like so
[White Bar at top of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsCNY.jpg)

I don't use `storyboard` and instead create all elements programatically. I am currently testing on an `iPhone X`

this is the code for the scrollview

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PureLayout

class profileView: UIScrollView {

    var shouldSetupConstraints = true
    var profileImageContainer = UIView()
    var profileImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
    var profileInfo = UIView()
    var name = UILabel()

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    let profilegradient = CAGradientLayer()
    let textFieldAppearance = UITextField.appearance()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: (96/255.0), green: (95/255.0), blue: (95/255.0), alpha: 0.65).cgColor , UIColor(red: (35/255.0), green: (39/255.0), blue: (42/255.0), alpha: 1).cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.cornerRadius = 4

        profilegradient.colors = [UIColor(red: (96/255.0), green: (95/255.0), blue: (95/255.0), alpha: 0.65).cgColor , UIColor(red: (35/255.0), green: (39/255.0), blue: (42/255.0), alpha: 1).cgColor]
        profilegradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        profilegradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)

        profileImageContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
        profilegradient.frame = profileImageContainer.bounds
        profileImageContainer.layer.insertSublayer(profilegradient, at:0)

        self.addSubview(profileImageContainer)

        profileImage.center = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width/2, y:screenSize.height/2)

        profileImageContainer.addSubview(profileImage)


        profileInfo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenSize.height/1.3, width: screenSize.width, height: 150)
        gradient.frame = profileInfo.bounds
        profileInfo.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at:0)

        self.addSubview(profileInfo)

        name.frame = CGRect(x: screenSize.width/20, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 50)
        name.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-medium", size: 32)
        name.textColor = .white

        profileInfo.addSubview(name)

        textFieldAppearance.keyboardAppearance = .light
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if(shouldSetupConstraints) {
            // AutoLayout constraints
            shouldSetupConstraints = false
        }
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In file info.list, add row: `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set to `NO`

```
 Next in appdelegate:

 UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent


 i hope work for you!
```